# Dynamic Windows.Arrange

Tags: excel, dynamic, vba

Windows 7, Office 2010.  I have a macro that opens a second window on the same workbook and displays the two horizontally.  I need to view two different sheets simultaneously.

I'm trying to get the upper window to display four rows (the header and three data rows) and the lower window to use the rest of the space.  I can arbitrarily force the upper and lower windows to fixed heights.

But this is unsatisfactory because it assumes a certain screen resolution.  Also, when forcing the windows to fixed heights, collapsing the Ribbon (Ctrl + F1) no longer dynamically resizes the two windows.

```
Dim workbookName as String

workbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveWindow.NewWindow
ActiveWorkbook.Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlHorizontal, ActiveWorkbook:=True
Windows(workbookName & ":2").Activate
Sheets("Report").Select   ' Is this necessary?

With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
    .FreezePanes = True
    .Height = 283
End With

Windows(workbookName & ":1").Activate
Sheets("Breakout").Select

With ActiveWindow
    .FreezePanes = False
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
    .FreezePanes = True
    .Top = 284.5
    .Height = 408
End With
```

So I'd like to 1) Set the upper window to display four rows, 2) Set the lower window to dynamically fill in the remaining space.  Thanks in advance.  --Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify like that:

```
Dim workbookName As String
Dim UpH As Integer

Dim workbookName As String
Dim UpH As Integer

workbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveWindow.NewWindow
ActiveWorkbook.Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlHorizontal, ActiveWorkbook:=True
Windows(workbookName & ":2").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select   ' Is this necessary?

With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
    .FreezePanes = True
    .Height = .Height - .UsableHeight    ' To found the Min Height
    .Height = .Height + Range("A1:A3").Height
    UpH = .Height
End With

Windows(workbookName & ":1").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Select

With ActiveWindow
    .FreezePanes = False
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
    .FreezePanes = True
    .Top = UpH + 1
    .Height = Application.UsableHeight - .Top
End With
```

the set of the first Height it's to force to have the min value of the windows height (with 0 cells). After you add the height of the range of the first n cells (in this case 3)...
The second windows use the data of the first...

Comment: It works correctly.  I changed the range to "A1:A4", as four rows need to display.  I also changed UpH to Long.